# Datatype mismatch in anchor and recursive part of a recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am running this SQL code on SQL Server to print alphabets from A to Z:

```
;with alphaCte as 
(
    select 'A' as letter
    union all
    select char(ascii(letter)+1) 
    from alphaCte 
    where letter < 'Z'
)
select * from alphaCte
```

I get this error:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "letter" of recursive query "alphaCte".

To rectify it, I have to make below change.

```
;with alphaCte as 
(
    select char(ascii('A')) as letter
    union all
    select char(ascii(letter)+1) 
    from alphaCte 
    where letter < 'Z'
)
select * from alphaCte
```

which works fine.

Could anyone please explain why my original code is throwing this datatype mismatch error?

Comment: A string is not a character

Comment: 'A' defaults to varchar I believe

Comment: The first pass is a varchar(1) while the subsequent passes would be a char(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment

```
Select column_ordinal
      ,name
      ,system_type_name 
 From sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('select ''A'' as letter,char(ascii(''A'')+1) as letter2',null,null )
```

Results

```
column_ordinal  name      system_type_name
1               letter    varchar(1)
2               letter2   char(1)
```

EDIT:  Just an aside... Recursive CTEs are great but datasets are better :)

```
Select Top 26 C=char(64+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) ) 
 From  master..spt_values n
```

Comment: Thanks. Is master..spt_values used as a dummy table in last query?

Comment: It is just a standard table build-in with SQL Server.  Any table of adequate size will do.